# Should I use verb or verb + ing in the following case?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, sentence

> Marla glanced at her watch. Half past four. She'd been in the subway
>   since morning, doing nothing in particular—**just watching trains come
>   and go, people getting on and off.** A typical commuting scene.

My first impulse was just to write *getting* instead of *get*. But after reading the sentence again I said: wait I wrote *come* and *go* shouldn't I write *get* instead? But after replacing it with *get* something seemed off.

So I'm a bit confused, should I use *get* or *getting*?

Comment: It's quite OK to 'watch people get on and off trains', and to 'watch people getting on and off trains'. You can choose whichever sounds better in context - punchier vs habitual. The problem comes with the imbalance of bare-infinitive and -ing form catenations. _He watched Bell bat and Onions bowling._

Comment: The question is about *watching* with *get/getting,* not *watch or watched.* You're doing a complete rewrite, which is not what was asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Just watching trains come and go* is fine, and so is *just watching people get on and off.* A problem arises when you try to put the two together. If you write *Just watching trains come and go, people get on and off*, the syntax isn’t immediately obvious. It sounds as if *people get on and off* is a new finite clause, when *get*, like *come* and *go* is, in my view, a bare infinitive. It will be clearer if you write *getting on and off*, but if you use that, it might be as well to change *come and go* to *coming and going* to create a parallel structure. That, however, does create rather a lot of *-ing* forms, one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

It's *getting* because you're not talking about a one time event. Whenever you are talking about a continuous action without a definite end, you use the progressive tenses (*auxiliary verb + verb + -ing*)

In this case you're using the present perfect progressive because the action began in the past and is still happening. You're actually saying *She had been watching people getting on and off.*

Comment: No - there is a choice here. Getting on / off a train is punctual for each person; you can certainly have "She watched John get on the train." The overall scenario, covering a whole morning of such activities, certainly also licenses the continuous.

Comment: You switched the tense. Now it is in the past and has a discreet end. The action in the example is ongoing. In the example, it would awkward to use watching and get.

Comment: The ratio of Google hits for "watching birds arrive" : "watching birds arriving" is 56 700 : 5. Switching 'trains' for 'birds' roughly equalises the returns. As Barrie says, " 'Watching trains come and go' is fine, and so is 'watching people get on and off' ". The watching is durative, the getting on / off and the coming and going can be regarded as punctual.

Comment: You're not getting it. I agree with Barrie England, you're misreading what he said. You left out the part where he says they are fine separately, but not when joined together. We both gave different reasons as to why *getting* is correct, but we both agreed that it was correct nonetheless. You keep insisting on reconstructing the sentence when in fact that is not what is asked.

Comment: No. As is obvious in my first comment, I'm disagreeing with your imperious 'It's _getting_ because you're not talking about a one time event.' - where you don't address the balance that Barrie does (and I too agree with his reasoning about the sentence as a whole). I'm saying Barrie's reason holds but yours needs toning down. The continuous tenses are used for durative processes, but here, individual punctual events may also be indicated, with a bare infinitive clause. Google hits for "watching him build" : "watching him building" number 1 100 000 : 200 000. Please stop muddying the waters.

Comment: I'm a native speaker. I don't need a Google search to tell me what is correct. If you want to argue with me, then take it to chat. Otherwise provide your own answer. I could not duplicate a previous answer. I gave another explanation. And you have made your opinion known.

Answer (score 0):

I thought below small change could solve this issue a lot better.

just watching trains come and go, and people getting on and off.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I wrote?

Comment: But this seems to imply that the trains' arrivals and departures individually take less time than the passengers' stepping on and off - it still doesn't have the nicely balanced parallel structure that seems stylistically preferable.  "She'd been in the subway since morning, doing nothing in particular — just watching trains coming and going, people getting on and off."  or, more staccato: "She'd been in the subway since morning, doing nothing in particular — just watching trains come and go. People get on and off."

Comment: @jano It's not the same. In this example, Hemant added an 'and', presumably to make the separation of ideas, and thus the parallelism, clearer. Although if that's what he meant, he ought to have said so.